# Hide auth tokens of a hls stream with dynamic JavaScript obfuscation using php to prevent curling

Tags: javascript, php, curl, obfuscation

I have a website that streams some tv channels. All are HLS streams.

SO, for each m3u8 file, we attach an authentication token (Ex. xxxx.m3u8?t=xxxxxx&e=xxxxx). this token will work for all channels for few minute.

With my current week security, all unauthorized website owners are curling any channel page and extracting that auth token to use with my static m3u8 files.

Here is my player code,

```
<div id="oWhrSRcF4qjyr0x"><div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var logo = "http://example/logo.png
var link = "http://example.com
jwplayer("oWhrSRcF4qjyr0x").setup({
"autostart":true,
"androidhls":"true",
"stretching": "exactfit",
"file":"http://example.com/stream.m3u8?t=xxxxxx&e=xxxxx",
"logo": {"file":logo,"margin":"-0", "position":"top-left","hide":"false","link":link},
});
</script>
```

In the above player, `"file":"http://example.com/stream.m3u8?t=xxxxxx&e=xxxxx",` keeps on changing for few minutes.

What i want to do here is obfuscating the entire player element not just the auth token from my server using php. i am aware that obfuscated code can be revealed easily, but here the token keeps on changing. i dont want a simple php file on their site to get auth token from my site.

Also, in my opinion, they cant use entire page as it contains my site logo.

I would be glad if anyone can help me with these.

- protecting my auth token.
- prevent curling my player.

Also, i tried to prevent curling my player by adding a session id to all links, but people are smart to bypass it, also i tried to obfuscated with [Dean Edwards 's Packer](http://joliclic.free.fr/php/javascript-packer/en/),
Its not a hiding everything. i just want to make the token not to be extracted alone.

So, please suggest any tool like that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service**! You have to show that you've put some efford into solving your own problem.

Comment: No, i tried to prevent curling my player by adding a session id to all links, but people are smart to bypass it, also i tried to obfuscated with [Dean Edwards 's Packer](http://joliclic.free.fr/php/javascript-packer/en/),
Its not a hiding everything. i just want to make the token not to be extracted alone.

So, please suggest any tool like that.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Most importantly I'm missing any code in your question. You're only explaining your situation and ask for a general solution that may or may not work in your case. We can't provide you with an _answer_ to your question. All we can do is guess. Hence no one is giving you an answer.

Comment: Sorry, i added my player code that contains a dynamic token, which i dont want to be extracted by others.

Comment: Perhaps you could use Ajax to extract the token from a PHP file instead. That way the token isn't inside your client side source at all. It's server side. Hence it can't be extracted.

Comment: But people can check the Ajax request Url in javascript, can we hide that atleast.

Comment: @icecub Thanks friend your idea, that is working flawless, i will use that for time being. I obfuscated it, its working fine, Will people able to find out the actual ajax request url may be by sniffing network.

Comment: They can see the url. But obfuscating it won't help. They just write a script that automaticly removes the obfuscation and you're facing the same problem again. If you really want to protect your streams, there's a simple trick that should work. Just put the `m3u8` file inside a directory protected by a htaccess file that blocks access to everyone except your own server. That way no one can directly access the stream. Only through your website